# Python.h found by locate but not by GCC

Tags: python, c

I just wrote a simple C executable to check if `Python.h` is working or not

```
#include<Python.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("this is a python header file included programm\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, it does not do much. However, when I try to compile it with `gcc` it gives me an error:

```
foo.c:1:19: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory.
```

Then I checked to see if the [python-dev [image: Install python-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/python-dev) package has `Python.h` installed or not using `locate`.

```
$locate Python.h
/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
```

It is clear to me that I have the `Python.h` header file on my system. How do I get my executable working?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Correct me if I'm wrong, but I would assume that the compiler isn't finding Python.h because it's not in your working directory and the full path hasn't been specified.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to qualify your include

```
#include <python2.7/Python.h>
```

Or tell gcc where to find Python.h with the

```
gcc -I /usr/include/python2.7/ program.c
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to provide GCC with the include path for the `Python.h` header. This can be done with the `-I` flag:

```
gcc -c -I/usr/include/python2.7 sourcefile.c
```

However, there is a better way: use [pkg-config [image: Install pkg-config]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pkg-config):

```
pkg-config --cflags python
```

This will output the flags that need to be passed to GCC in order to compile applications that use the Python headers and libraries.

When linking, use the output of this command to include the appropriate libraries:

```
pkg-config --libs python
```

You could even combine both steps with:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs python` sourcefile.c
```

Comment: After "gcc -c -I..." I've got onlye file with .o extension, how can I get an executable file ?

Comment: @RS You need to link it, try doing something like this: `"gcc file.o -o program"`

Comment: Please look this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/706471/undefined-references-with-cython